# Symfony Cache doctrine/orm/Proxies failed to open stream /Proxy/AbstractProxyFactory.php on line 209

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm, doctrine

I'm try to move symfony to shared host.

I moved symfony structure to / and my web folder is /public_html.

> Warning: require(/home/user/app/cache/prod/doctrine/orm/Proxies/__CG__UserBundleEntityUser.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /home/user/vendor/doctrine/common/lib/Doctrine/Common/Proxy/AbstractProxyFactory.php on line 209
>
> Warning: require(/home/user/app/cache/prod/doctrine/orm/Proxies/__CG__UserBundleEntityUser.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /home/user/vendor/doctrine/common/lib/Doctrine/Common/Proxy/AbstractProxyFactory.php on line 209
>
> Fatal error: require(): Failed opening required '/home/user/app/cache/prod/doctrine/orm/Proxies/__CG__UserBundleEntityUser.php' (include_path='.:/opt/php55/lib/php') in /home/user/vendor/doctrine/common/lib/Doctrine/Common/Proxy/AbstractProxyFactory.php on line 209

This error occurs only in the `prod` environment. The exception is not thrown in the `dev` environment.

I tried the following:

```
rm -rf /app/cache + chmod 777
app/console cache:warmup
```

I use Symfony 2.8.3. The following directories are present locally and on the server:

LOCAL CACHE:
- /annotations, /twig, /vich_uploader + /doctrine, /translations

SERVER CACHE:
- /annotations, /twig, /vich_uploader

If I upload my local cache to the server, the exception disappears.

Comment: did you run `app/console cache:warmup --env=prod` ? This command generated the proxy caches actually ...

Comment: yes, i run. This no return error, return message warmup generate. But the folder doctrine is mission in app/cache/prod.

Comment: I provided an answer that will resolve the issue. Enable automatic proxy class generation in your configuration for the `prod` environment.

Answer (score 83, accepted):

You did not create the proxy classes before you tried to access your application. This is usually done by:

```
app/console cache:warmup --env=prod
```

The auto-generation of proxy-classes is **disabled** by default in the `prod` environment. You can enable automatic generation of proxy-classes similar to the `dev` environment by adding this to your config:

**app/config/config_prod.yml**

```
doctrine:
    orm:
        auto_generate_proxy_classes:  true # <- change to true
        proxy_dir:            '%kernel.cache_dir%/doctrine/orm/Proxies'
        proxy_namespace:      Proxies
```

Comment: **This solved the problem.** Before my config have only this auto_generate_proxy_classes: "%kernel.debug%". **Thanks**

Comment: There's a typo on the first line, it's `doctrine:` :)

Comment: "The auto-generation of proxy-classes is disabled by default in the prod environment" why is that? should i let it enabled forever or disabled it again?

Comment: In my case, I didn't manage to warn my cache using the command, but setting it to auto did actually work (dooh ?).

Comment: If auto_generate_proxy_classes is on, it will generate the proxy files on each request! You want that in development so you have not to do this manually each time you change something. You don't want this in production because it will kill your server at a certain amount of requests (which happened to a product I worked on at around 1k requests per second ;)

Comment: @Mischa but without this setting turned on it won't create Proxy in general. What would you suggest instead?

Comment: @itinance I suggest to read this [Doctrine Cookbook for advanced configuration](https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/2.9/reference/advanced-configuration.html#development-vs-production-configuration), as it explains it in detail much better then I could :)

Answer (score 1):

/app/config/doctrine.yml

Change from:

```
  orm:
    auto_generate_proxy_classes: "%kernel.debug%"
```

To:

```
  orm:
    auto_generate_proxy_classes: true
```

Works!

Answer (score -1):

I have changed all files that refer to the expression **'auto_generate_proxy_classes'** (I've changed the value from 'false' to 'true') and this fixed the issue:

1. ... /vendor/doctrine/doctrine-bundle/DoctrineBundle.php
2. ... /vendor/doctrine/doctrine-bundle/Resources/doc/configuration.rst
3. ... /vendor/doctrine/doctrine-bundle/DependencyInjection/Configuration.php
4. ... /vendor/doctrine/doctrine-bundle/DependencyInjection/DoctrineExtension.php
5. ... /app/config/config.php
6. ... /app/cache/prod/appProdProjectContainer.php

Comment: you should never change files in /vendor