# FosUserBundle + Symfony 3.4

Tags: fosuserbundle, symfony-3.4

Since 7 days I tried to repair HwiOauthFukingBundle with facebook + FosUserOtherFukingBundle + Symfony 3.4.

And now, I have this incomprehensible errors in prod but not in dev.

> [2018-03-17 14:45:27] php.WARNING: Warning:
>   require(/var/www/vhosts/domaine.fr/var/cache/prod/doctrine/orm/Proxies/__CG__ECUserBundleEntityImage.php):
>   failed to open stream: No such file or directory
>   {"exception":"[object] (ErrorException(code: 0): Warning:
>   require(/var/www/vhosts/domaine.fr/var/cache/prod/doctrine/orm/Proxies/__CG__ECUserBundleEntityImage.php):
>   failed to open stream: No such file or directory at
>   /var/www/vhosts/domaine.fr/vendor/doctrine/common/lib/Doctrine/Common/Proxy/AbstractProxyFactory.php:223)"}
>   []

And this one

> [2018-03-17 14:45:27] request.CRITICAL: Uncaught PHP Exception
>   Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalErrorException: "Compile Error:
>   require(): Failed opening required
>   '/var/www/vhosts/domaine.fr/var/cache/prod/doctrine/orm/Proxies/__CG__ECUserBundleEntityImage.php'
>   (include_path='.:/opt/plesk/php/7.1/share/pear')" at
>   /var/www/vhosts/domaine.fr/vendor/doctrine/common/lib/Doctrine/Common/Proxy/AbstractProxyFactory.php
>   line 223 {"exception":"[object]
>   (Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalErrorException(code: 0):
>   Compile Error: require(): Failed opening required
>   '/var/www/vhosts/domaine.fr/var/cache/prod/doctrine/orm/Proxies/__CG__ECUserBundleEntityImage.php'
>   (include_path='.:/opt/plesk/php/7.1/share/pear') at
>   /var/www/vhosts/domaine.fr/vendor/doctrine/common/lib/Doctrine/Common/Proxy/AbstractProxyFactory.php:223)"}
>   []

What's going on ?

I have clean the cache folder etc. but this error seems to be falling from the sky... this is a nightmare...

Comment: Check this link - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36255440/ Looks like the same issue.

Comment: @ElvisPlesky Thank you, indeed it works

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Symfony Cache doctrine/orm/Proxies failed to open stream /Proxy/AbstractProxyFactory.php on line 209](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36255440/symfony-cache-doctrine-orm-proxies-failed-to-open-stream-proxy-abstractproxyfac)